# Multiple references to a single google analytics account on one page

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to pin down the reason for a discrepancy in Google Ecommerce tracking for a client, with most reports reporting values about 10 times higher than they should be.

So far the only fault I've been able to find in the tracking implementation is that `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);`

is being set twice, both times to point at the same account.

This seems like it might potentially mess up the tracking, but the analytics console I'm using is reporting normal beacon activity.

Does anyone know if this configuration has any effect on how Google reports data?

Comment: "Should be" as compared to what, and which values (hits and visits, or e-commerce values like revenue etc) ?

Comment: are all of the metrics in e-commerce reporting 10 times higher? look at the e-commerce tags and see if the values correspond with the actual orders...

Answer (score 1):

This won't bother Google, the second call will simply overwrite the first (would be different for trackPageView or trackEvent or other interaction calls, but not a problem when you set the account id).